# How To reflect the required data with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have call to use Mongoose to send the list of all projects as follows:

```
Project.find({ uid: req.user._id })
            .then((project) => {
                res.status(200).send({
                    status: "success",
                    data: {project},
                    message: "successful"
                });
            })
```

How can I remove the creation date and modification date from the project object?

Exp response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "project": [
            {
                "_id": "5e8baea9fe729e4d78855332",
                "uid": "5e89c1bd2566a6360cf78097",
                "project_name": "Test 00",
                "updated_date": "2020-04-06T22:35:21.555Z",
                "created_date": "2020-04-06T22:35:21.555Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e8bb4f5fadc384eb73c6d59",
                "uid": "5e89c1bd2566a6360cf78097",
                "project_name": "Test 11",
                "updated_date": "2020-04-06T23:02:13.498Z",
                "created_date": "2020-04-06T23:02:13.498Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "successful"
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve, your question is no clear

Comment: I want to hide the creation and editing date from the data I received response (remove, or whatever you call it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Project.find({ uid: req.user._id },{updated_date:0,created_date:0})
            .then((project) => {
                res.status(200).send({
                    status: "success",
                    data: {project},
                    message: "successful"
                });
            })
```

You can choose to hide some fields by doing eg `{updated_date:0,created_date:0}` this will not show `updated_date` and `created_date`. but if you use 1 it will show

Comment: Here is the answer I am looking for, it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator, something like:

```js
let response = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "project": [
            {
                "_id": "5e8baea9fe729e4d78855332",
                "uid": "5e89c1bd2566a6360cf78097",
                "project_name": "Test 00",
                "updated_date": "2020-04-06T22:35:21.555Z",
                "created_date": "2020-04-06T22:35:21.555Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e8bb4f5fadc384eb73c6d59",
                "uid": "5e89c1bd2566a6360cf78097",
                "project_name": "Test 11",
                "updated_date": "2020-04-06T23:02:13.498Z",
                "created_date": "2020-04-06T23:02:13.498Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "successful"
}

response.data.project.map((p) => {
  delete p.created_date;
  delete p.updated_date;
});

console.log(response.data.project);
```

> The JavaScript `delete` operator removes a property from an object; if
>   no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually
>   released automatically.